# Re-Installing google play

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google

I got my google play and google play services deleted from my rooted phone.I had moved all the apps on internal apps to my partitioned sd card,which got corrupted.Tried installing google play apk and services from other sites but they would not install.
Phone model:Galaxy Y S5630

Need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflash gapps from recovery. This will install all the necessary google applications that have been deleted.

You can find all gapps on [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps), you just have to choose the ones relevant to your android version.